# Variables not being passed to Function

Tags: php, variables

I'm just getting back into PHP programming again and I can't seem to figure this one out.

I'm just trying to write a simple login screen, but I can't seem to pass variables to my "Login" function.

So this is the code I have that is called on the post page...

```
$Email = $_POST["Email_Address"];
    $Password = $_POST["Password"];

    // check to see if the login is valid
    $ValidLogin = ValidateLogin($Email, $Password, $ErrorMessage);
```

I previously declare ValidateLogin in a separate include file which is called before this code.

```
function ValidateLogin($EmailAddress, $Password, &$ErrorMessage){

    $ErrorMessage = ""; 


}
```

When I look at the variables within the ValidateLogin function, they are blank?  I had this code working on another project, but don't understand why it's not working here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. Please provide more details.

Comment: Your question is kind of incomplete. Consider re-writing it with more code and clarification. Right now it's impossible to figure out your issue because you aren't really even using that function.

Comment: Please don't pass `$errorMessage` by reference, but rather `return` all the needed info.

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Obvious question is obvious: Your HTML form is using POST as a method and does contain inputs with those names, right?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I won't use by-reference variables - **since by-reference is far less by reference, than in other languages**. Due to this fact, the by-reference parameter declaration tends to render ugly problems.

There I'd write this method, which **returns a logical value and an error message**:

```
/**
*
* Checks email-address and password vs. the list of all valid user credentials.
* Returns an array, with two elements
*  [0]  -> TRUE iff. credentials are valid
*  [1]  -> An error-message, which may be posted to the result web-page
*
* @param string $EmailAddress - An email-address
* @param string $Password - A password
* @returns array - array( bool, string )
*/
function ValidateLogin( $EmailAddress, $Password ){

   // Do whatever is possible to verify credentials
   return array( TRUE, 'this is a message' );

}
```

You'd use this method like this:

```
$Email = $_POST["Email_Address"];
$Password = $_POST["Password"];

// check to see if the login is valid
list( $ValidLogin, $errorMessage ) = ValidateLogin( $Email, $Password );
```

Note that `list()` is a language construct, which splits a list. Find the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

**POST method of FORM element**

Please not, that your form needs to read like this to pass values as `$_POST` to PHP:

```
<form action="theActualScriptname.php" method="post">
   ... form elements ..
</form>
```

Don't forget: The `method` attribute of the `form` element is essential!

Comment: Hope you don't mind that I removed the `ErrorMessage` entirely. I don't think it makes sense to already have it before validating anything. If you disagree feel free to rollback. :)

Comment: @PeeHaa Thank you! You are welcome! Definitely, the third parameter is fully superfluous.

Comment: I got rid of the By Ref Error Message after I posted the question actually.  I know it's not best practice, it was kind of a quick fix to get that previous project up and running because of new requirements and I just didn't feel like re-writing the whole thing at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Back to the original issue, I did get it working.  It seems like it was a scope issue, the function was declared within a Switch block where I include files with function declarations (In this case, ValidateLogin()).  The function was being called outside of the Switch Block.  When I moved the function declaration it worked.

I find it odd, that it ran the function regardless, but just didn't pass the parameters, they were all blank.  I stepped through the code using Eclipse/XDebug and I can see the parameters, just disappear once I stepped into the function.

Maybe someone can enlighten me on why this occurs?  Why does it call the function, but not pass the parameters.

Comment: Ok, I found the issue, it's Eclipse/XDebug.  In some cases, it doesn't show Parameter Values when they're being passed to a function, but the code is actually seeing those parameters.

Comment: Please don't bury answers in comments, and don't use answers to ask follow-up questions. Clarifications and additional questions go in the question body. The "Your Answer" field is strictly for your answer to the question as given. Comments are second-class citizens that are subject to deletion without further notice.